# vCard 4.0 doesn't display correctly, with labels ignored and wrong character decoding, among other things

Tags: vcf-vcard

I have created a vCard 4.0 file with a text editor according to [RFC 6350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) by IETF. It is simple, and looks kind of like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
KIND:individual
FN:René Descartes
N:Descartes;René;;;
TITLE:Façade Engineer
ADR;
  GEO="geo:46.975308,0.699597";
  LABEL="Headquarters":
  ;;29 Rue Descartes;;Descartes;37160;France
TEL;VALUE=uri;TYPE=home:tel:+33247597919
END:VCARD
```

The file is saved as `somename.vcf` (with CRLF and in UTF-8) and inspected on my iOS/macOS devices. However, the display of the file has many issues.

- Non-ASCII characters are not decoded correctly.
- The labels are all wrong.
- The URI scheme is prepended to the phone number.

It is as if vCard 4.0 is not supported at all. Or did I make any mistakes?

The screenshot is attached below.

[image: vCard example]

Comment: Aren't non-ascii characters supposed to be base64-encoded, and the character set specified?

Comment: @mivk §3.1 says 'The charset ... for vCard is UTF-8' and Appendix A says 'The CONTEXT and CHARSET parameters are no more'.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Another potential problem on Macs could be that it sometimes uses NFD UTF8. But I don't see how that could end up showing the output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Like you suggested, it looks to me like the client does not support vCard
  version 4. For example, URI-formatted telephone numbers are only supported by version 4, which might explain why it is not rendering the phone number properly. Try using a version 3 vCard.
- Your ADR property is formatted strangely. I might trying
  putting it all on one line to see if that makes any difference. If your intent is to make use of line
  folding, each additional line must be prefixed with a
  **single** space according to the RFC. You are using two spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, and for pointing out the line folding mistake!